# k-means vs k-median?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I know there is k-means clustering algorithm and k-median. One that uses the mean as the center of the cluster and the other uses the median. My question is: when/where to use which?

Comment: You are going to have to define *medians* (and perhaps calculate them) if you have more than one dimension; if you just take the median in each value then you lose rotational properties.  A further possibility is [*k*-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)

Answer (score 19):

k-means minimizes within-cluster variance, which equals squared Euclidean distances.

In general, the **arithmetic mean** does this. It does *not* optimize distances, but squared deviations from the mean.

k-medians minimizes absolute deviations, which equals Manhattan distance.

In general, the **per-axis median** should do this. It is a good estimator for the mean, if you want to minimize the sum of absolute deviations (that is sum_i abs(x_i-y_i)), instead of the squared ones.

It's not a question about accuracy. It's a question of correctness. ;-)

So here's your decision tree:

- If your distance is **squared Euclidean distance**, use **k-means**
- If your distance is **Taxicab metric**, use **k-medians**
- If you have **any other distance**, use **k-medoids**

Some exceptions: as far as I can tell, maximizing cosine similarity is related to minimizing squared Euclidean distance on L2-normalized data. So if your data is L2 normalized; and you l2-normalize your means each iteration, then you can use k-means again.

Comment: I somewhat take issue with the statement that the median minimizes manhattan distance, since there is no unique agreed on concept of a median for multidimensional data. It's not false, but I find it a misleading statement to make in a multidimensional context. There are multiple multidimensional generalizations of medians, many of which have no connection to minimizing manhattan distances.

Comment: I change this to per-axis median. I hope you are happier now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make an analysis not regarding of the possible effect of extreme values use k means but if you want to be more accurate use k median

Comment: Can you support and/or explain these assertions in any way?

Comment: Yeah can you elaborate more please? with examples?

Comment: I think that's because "Median" can tolerate the outliers but "Mean" is totally affected by them. For example: if we have the data points{1,2,3,5,78} its obvious that 78 is outlier. The median of these data is 3 and the mean is 17.8. So the median is the best way to summarize these data.

Comment: If you take the net-worth of the population of people in Wyoming and you run k-means, things are okay. Now, Bill Gates moves to Wyoming and k-means goes out of whack. But k-medians works fine. With k-medians, Bill Gates is just another resident of the state of Wyoming. But with k-means he's a major outlier to say the least.